# Why does the XFBML registration plugin go blank when used in IE?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, xfbml

I think I might be doing something wrong. Users that try and register with Internet Explorer say that the facebook plugin goes blank when trying to submit it. Any Ideas?

This is some of the code:

```
    <fb:registration redirect-uri="http://friendsconnect.org/----.php" 
fields='[{"name":"name"},{"name":"first_name"},{"name":"last_name"},{"name":"email"},{"name":"username","description":"Username","type":"text"},{"name":"password"},{"name":"gender"},{"name":"birthday"},{"name":"captcha"},]'
 onvalidate="validate"></fb:registration> 

<script> 
function validate(form) {
  errors = {};
  if (form.name == "") {
    errors.name = "Please enter your name.";
  }
    if (form.username == "") {
    errors.username = "Please enter your username.";
  }
  if (form.email == "") {
    errors.email = "Please enter your email address.";
  }
  if (form.password == "") {
    errors.password = "Please enter your password.";
  }
  if (form.gender == "") {
    errors.gender = "Please enter your sex.";
  }
  if (form.birthday == "") {
    errors.birthday = "Please enter your birthday.";
  }
  if (form.captcha == "") {
    errors.captcha = "Try and enter the text in the box below.";
  }
  return errors;
}
</script>
```

[image]

Comment: Just a note that the **XFBML** shouldn't be confused with the legacy **FBML**. Read [this](http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/462#fbml_roadmap).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using XHTML the most common problem is that the Facebook namespace isn't included in the HTML tag. This is the normal reason IE doesn't render FBML.

Your HTML tag will look like:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml">
```

This is part of the Legacy API.

Comment: It still is displaying a white area when submitted, I have added the html tag

Comment: Are you using the legacy API?

Comment: that's the original version of the API created by Facebook. a lot of it uses xfbml and requires you to have a cross-domain page, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your problem is [this bug](http://bugs.developers.facebook.net/show_bug.cgi?id=15236), which Facebook says they fixed yesterday, although I have not tested it to see if it is fixed.

> We believe this issue may be resolved.
>   Please make sure this line is in the
>   validation function: `errors = {};`
>
> If you're still seeing issues, can you
>   please test example function on
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/advanced/
>
> And reopen with a link to an example
>   if it does not work.